# Git for windows xp crashes all the time

Tags: windows-xp, git

I am trying to clone a git repo on windwos xp. 
I am using GIT BASH.
But everytime i try to clone it i get the error as below. 
I tried to restart my pc but this didn't help.

Any suggestions?

[image: Git clone issue]